# Кэширование полученных и доступных знаков рассинхронизировано

Tags: дефект, знаки, кэширование

Получаю новый знак за метку

> [image: скриншот знака]

нажимаю кнопку <kbd>Выбрать следующий знак</kbd> и вижу его в доступных:

> [image: скриншот доступных знаков]

Наверное, надо обновлять оба места одновременно?

Comment: Так кэш, он на то и кэш, чтобы проблемы кэша были рассинхронизированы. Подобные баги, как я понимаю, закрывают как «так задумано». Типа, ждите серверную полночь или что-то в этом духе.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ кэш на то и кэш, что имеет функцию delete ;)